# Google visualization API : Unable to add second vAxis

Tags: google-visualization

Problem :I am trying to create a combo of candlestick and line charts. The code below works if I do not specify/configure a second vAxis. But I need the second axis as the values for the second series are so large (more than  10 mil)  that the candlesticks (values < 500)  become almost invisible if plotted against the same axis. Appreciate any help!

```js
function drawVisualization() { 

var jstringfromWeb ={
                 "cols":[{"id":"ldate","label":"LDATE","type":"date"},
                         {"id":"open","label":"OPEN","type":"number"},
                         {"id":"high","label":"HIGH","type":"number"},
                         {"id":"low","label":"LOW","type":"number"},
                         {"id":"close","label":"CLOSE","type":"number"},
                         {"id":"totqty","label":"TOTQTY","type":"number"}],
                 "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 10, 25)"},{"v":377.2},{"v":387.1},{"v":377.2},{"v":386.15},{"v":381.0}]},
                         {"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 10, 26)"},{"v":387.65},{"v":391.4},{"v":379.05},{"v":390.25},{"v":58.0}]},
                         {"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 10, 27)"},{"v":393.5},{"v":399.9},{"v":392.6},{"v":399.2},{"v":67.0}]},
                         {"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 10, 28)"},{"v":403.1},{"v":405.05},{"v":394.6},{"v":397.9},{"v":91.0}]},
                         {"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 10, 29)"},{"v":399.0},{"v":401.85},{"v":395.3},{"v":398.7},{"v":48.0}]}]
                };
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jstringfromWeb);
var options = {title : 'My Candlestick Chart',
               hAxis: {title: "Date"}, 
               vAxes : [0: {minValue : 350, maxValue: 430}, 1: {minValue: 10 , maxValue :400}], 
               series: {0:{type :"candlesticks",targetAxisIndex: 0} , 1: {type : "bars" , targetAxisIndex : 1}}            
          };
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vAxes option is specified incorrectly, it should be an object not an array:

```
vAxes: {
    0: {
        maxValue: 8000
    },
    1: {
        maxValue: 200000000
    }
}
```